# KeyError: 'val_acc', but metrics = 'acc'

Tags: python, deep-learning

I am implementing my VGG16, however when I wish to check my val_acc, is shows KeyError: 'val_acc'. This is the code of my work:

```
#creating the model
opt = Adam(lr=0.001)

model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['acc'])

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("vgg16_1.h5", 
                             monitor='acc', 
                             verbose=1, 
                             save_best_only=True, 
                             save_weights_only=False, 
                             mode='auto', 
                             save_freq=1)

early = EarlyStopping(monitor='acc',
                      min_delta=0,
                      patience=5,
                      verbose=1,
                      mode='auto')

hist = model.fit(x=traindata,
                 steps_per_epoch=1,
                 validation_data=testdata,
                 validation_steps=10,
                 epochs=10,
                 callbacks=[checkpoint, early])

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(hist.history['acc'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_acc'])
plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])
plt.title("model accuracy")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.legend(["Accuracy","Validation Accuracy","Loss","Validation Loss"])
plt.show()
```

My Error Message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-f533b752c543> in <module>
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 plt.plot(hist.history['acc'])
----> 3 plt.plot(hist.history['val_acc'])
      4 plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
      5 plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])

KeyError: 'val_acc'
```

Can anyone please help me figure this out please?

Comment: Just print the contents of the `history` callback object and see what keys it has inside. Maybe validation accuracy is called differently for some reason.

Comment: can i know how should i do it? I do print(history) but it is not what I want

Comment: So what does it show when you do `print(history)`

Comment: <tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History object at 0x000002EF15E12A20>

Comment: this is the result i get

Comment: You could try print(hist.history.keys())

Comment: Also, try replacing acc by accuracy, val_acc by val_accuracy